# Binding JSON request data to command objects

Tags: json, grails, data-binding

In a Grails 2.5.X app, I can directly bind request data to a command object field of type `Map` like so:

```
class MyController {
  def myAction(Command command) {
    Map requestData = command.data
  }
}

class Command {
  Map data
}
```

It seems that internally Grails uses Gson for the parsing of the JSON data. If for example, the request data is `{"page": 6}` the corresponding `Map` will be

```
[page: new LazilyParsedNumber(6)]
```

i.e. the value stored in the `Map` is an instance of `com.google.gson.internal.LazilyParsedNumber`.

This is problematic for me. I would prefer if the `Map` were equivalent to that which would be created by:

```
new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText('{"page": 6}')
```

which is:

```
[page: new Integer(6)]
```

I've looked into the various options for [customising the databinding](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.4/guide/single.html#dataBinding), and none of them hook into the pipeline sufficiently early. In other words, no matter which of the options I choose, the request data has already been processed by Gson.

Is it possible to replace Gson with `JsonSlurper` as the default parser of JSON request data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to replace Gson with JsonSlurper as the default parser
>   of JSON request data?

Yes, but it isn't something that we document or provide any particular support hooks for.

The default JSON data binding source creator is at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v2.5.6/grails-web-databinding/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/binding/bindingsource/JsonDataBindingSourceCreator.groovy.

An instance of that class is added to the Spring application context by the data binding plugin at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/bd7cc10e17d34f20cedce979724f0e3bacd4cdb4/grails-plugin-databinding/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/databinding/DataBindingGrailsPlugin.groovy#L97.

One thing you could do is write your own class which extends `AbstractRequestBodyDataBindingSourceCreator` (or just implements `DataBindingSourceCreator`) and register an instance of that class as a bean named `jsonDataBindingSourceCreator` and that will replace the default one with yours.  Then you are on your own to use whatever techniques you like for parsing the body of the request and creating a `Map`.

Comment: jeff, sorry to ask here but do you happen to know the answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61876296/grails-3-binding-multiple-command-objects-via-post/71247913#71247913

Comment: @DavidHa I posted an answer there.  The person who posted the question responded to say that the solution I provided didn't work, the code seems to work and I was not able to understand the comments so I deleted my answer. He asked me to undelete my answer and edit it to include something that he is doing that is different, but that isn't my answer so I don't think that is right, so I left it deleted.